# Create table data if table data is not empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

I use this SQL script to generate test data with Liquibase. This script should be run every time when Spring Boot application is starting.

```
INSERT into tasks SELECT generate_series(1,355) AS id,
    ('Business name ' || generate_series(1,355)) AS business_name,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS status,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS task_type,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS updated_at;
```

The problem is that I get this issue when I run the script more than one times:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tasks_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

I use this Hibernate configuration to create a table:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

is it possible to generate always new additional rows when the script is run?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create the id as an auto-increment primary key and then you can insert whatever records you want into the table without worrying about the id field?

Comment: Can you give more details, please?

Comment: Do you mean more details on how to do this? Search your postgresql documentation for the word “serial”

Comment: If `id` is already setup as a standard primary key (which it may be given that the unique constraint is called `tasks_pkey`) you may be able to just remove the `generate_series(1,355) AS id,` from your code. The ID will get assigned without you doing anything.

Comment: ok looks like the proper way is to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` with Postgres